# Why does Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 think that Chrome is an Electronic Medical Record (EMR) program?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, dragon-naturally-speaking

If I go to http://wikicfp.com/cfp/servlet/event.showcfp?eventid=73992&copyownerid=86856 on Chrome, then try to turn on Dragon, I get the error message:

> Program not supported. "EMR restriction" in Help

which turn off Dragon.

[image]

Why?

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 Professional with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. I don't have this issue on other webpages that I have visited so far and dictated into.

Comment: Franck - Upon quick research, it seems that this application functionality uses DNS and has hard-coded logic that checks DNS so just out of curiosity, try going to http://97.107.135.119/cfp/servlet/event.showcfp?eventid=73992&copyownerid=86856 via that IP address rather than the domain name and see if the Nuance software does the same.

Comment: Furthermore, it seems the word "Healtcare" is on that site and the EMR restriction of the software you are using if per it not being of the "medical" flavor/version so it may be picking up on keywords from content of sites you visit enforcing it's licensing rules with the product you are using. So perhaps there is some hard-coded DNS site checks as well as some keyword searches it does on sites you want to use its functionality and if it feels it's "medical" related then it does not allow you to use with that license for that site. The solution is to upgrade or report false positive to support

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Thanks, you are correct. I'll keep you posted when I try with Dragon Professional Individual 15. I'm not going to contact Nuance because their website is a mess, they closed their user forum http://nuance-community.custhelp.com/offline.html, they don't disclose the list of reported issues,  they should monitor Stack Exchange anyway, amongst other reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not definitive for your exact use case, [this KnowBrainer forum post](https://www.knowbrainer.com/forums/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=4&threadid=8922) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20180404192440/https://www.knowbrainer.com/forums/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=4&threadid=8922)) regarding an older version of Dragon Naturally Speaking states that *any* non-Medical version of Dragon uses potential keywords related to a window to block EMR applications.  From the post (emphasis added):

> If we send you an e-mail about a new liquid soap product that you should try and put the word “soap” in the subject line, you will not be able to [use] NaturallySpeaking Ver. 10 [to] respond or even delete our message unless you are using [Dragon NaturallySpeaking] Medical because NaturallySpeaking additionally looks through its EMR hit list in Window titles.
>
> The word “soap” is on the disallowed hit list because NaturallySpeaking suspects that you may be attempting to use a non-Medical 10 version of [Dragon] in S.O.A.P. Notes (a well-known EMR application).  **Additionally, you will not be able to dictate on certain forums such as eClinicalWorks.**

And while eClinicalWorks is a self-described "cloud EHR", this last line seems to indicate Dragon can potentially recognize and filter web pages based on this criteria (since the web page title is typically the browser window title as well).

Comment: That's an ugly restriction, especially with overloaded terms.